# MySQL JOIN and Contains

Tags: mysql, join

I have five tables, that are a big mess, and Im trying to do a JOIN on.

```
Tbl - USERS
id - name
---------
1
2
3
4
5

Tbl - SESSION1
id | user_id | date
--------------------
1    1         1/1/11
2    2         1/2/11
3    3         1/2/11
4    5         1/3/11

Tbl - SESSION2
id | user_id | date
--------------------
1    1         1/1/12
2    2         1/1/12
3    4         1/2/12
5    5         1/2/12

Table - QA
id | user_id | session_id | question                      | answer
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1    1         1            Did you go on vacation?         Y
2    1         1            Did you like it there?          N
3    1         2            Did you have travel insurance?  N
4    3         1            Did you go on vacation?         Y
5    3         1            Did you like it there?          N
6    3         1            Did you have travel insurance?  N

Table - QA2
id | user_id | session_id | question         | answer
--------------------------------------------------------
1    1         1            Country Visited    Cuba
2    1         2            Country Visited    Mexico
```

I want to run a query to get the following data back in a join, the the most effecient. I need to check that user has answer yes to the question, "have you been on vacation".

```
user_id | session 1 | session 2 | question             | answer | country
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         1/1/11    null          been on vacation       yes      cuba
1         1/1/11    null          had travel insurance   no       cuba
1         null      1/1/12        been on vacation       yes      mexico
1         null      1/1/12        had travel insurance   no       mexico
```

**Update/Disclaimer:** I did not design this schema and I cannot make changes.

Comment: why are there two session tables?

Comment: ... and two QA's? And why do you say you have 3 tables when clearly you have 5 (although you *should* have 3 ? :-(

Comment: I don't know why there are two session tables.

Comment: This is such a bad design that you'd be better off biting the bullet now and redesigning it and then migrating the data into your new database.

Comment: I repeat again. I cannot/will not be redesigning this schema.